# meaning of enqueue_head macro linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am not sure what is the meaning of the macro `ENQUEUE_HEAD` in linux mean. I have an intuition that it means to enqueue a task after it has woke up but still want to be sure.

Note: For reference purposes in v3.5.4 it is defined in `/include/linux/sched.h` and referenced at many place but one such place I am having problem is function `enqueue_task_rt` in file `./kernel/sched/rt.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sched: Add enqueue/dequeue flags

ENQUEUE_HEAD - the waking task should be placed on the head
of the priority queue (where appropriate).

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1004.0/00744.html